# javascript deuobfuscation - what this code do?

Tags: javascript, malware, deobfuscation

I know a little bit of JS, but on some 'stage' I can not understand what this code is doing:

code:

```
<script>
n="3.5#3.5#51.5#50#15#19#49#54.5#48.5#57.5#53.5(...)"[((e)?"s":"")+"p"+"lit"]("a#"[((e)?"su":"")+"bstr"](1));
```

Of course 'n' is the var, but how the string inside (prepare for eval() later) is 'encoded'? 
I mean: the real question probably is: what means after this string:

```
[((e)?"s":"")+"p"+"lit"]("a#"[((e)?"su":"")+"bstr"](1));
```

?

Thanks for any advice StackOverflow.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is unlikely to be of use to anyone else.

Comment: I see no harm, it does help people to be able to understand some of the more advanced program flow of javascript, albeit ugly flow.

Comment: @MiltoxBeyond the ternary operator, string concatenation, `substr()`, and `['key']` property access are all covered _at length_ all over SO. There's nothing new here.

Comment: @Mathletics: Speaking of nitpicking, it's ***a*** ternary operator, not *the* ternary operator. It's *the* conditional operator. Okay, granted, there's only one ternary operator (an operator accepting three operands) in JavaScript *at the moment*... ;-) *(ducks and runs...)*

Comment: @T.J.Crowder this is a good reminder to finish my coffee before getting pedantic ^_^

Answer (score 2):

If `e` is truthy (and I'm sure it must be), then

```
((e)?"s":"")+"p"+"lit"
```

becomes

```
"split"
```

and

```
((e)?"su":"")+"bstr"
```

becomes

```
"substr"
```

Giving us

```
n="3.5#3.5#51.5#50#15#19#49#54.5#48.5#57.5#53.5(...)"["split"]("a#"["substr"](1));
```

...which is the same as

```
n="3.5#3.5#51.5#50#15#19#49#54.5#48.5#57.5#53.5(...)".split("a#".substr(1));
```

...which is the same as

```
n="3.5#3.5#51.5#50#15#19#49#54.5#48.5#57.5#53.5(...)".split("#");
```

...which gives us `n` =

```
["3.5", "3.5", "51.5", "50", "15", "19", "49", "54.5", "48.5", "57.5", "53.5(...)"]
```

Comment: Do you think this will be useful to future visitors of the site? It _might_ be if you explained the ternary operator and string concatenation, but those are language basics and are both covered, at length, elsewhere. (Sorry, I'll take my nitpicking back to meta.) :)

Comment: Thank you all for your comments and answers.   Mathletics: ihmo it will be useful because (even if it is a basic in JS) other 'new guys' can get the idea of 'basics in JS obfuscation' ;)  MiltoxBeyond: thanks, this is the idea ;) T.J. Crowder - big thanks for your answer!